# Facebook Graph API search posts with picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Im using the Facebook php API in order to search public posts with a specific hashtag in it.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
  require 'facebookauth/facebook.php';

  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId'  => 'myappid',
     'secret' => 'myappsecret',
  ));

  $query = urlencode('hashtag');
  $type = 'post';
  $ret = $facebook->api('/search?q='.$query.'&type='.$type.'&limit=10000');
  echo json_encode($ret);
?>
```

My problem is that the above code doesn't return the posts that have an image attached.
I am posting from my profile a public post with the hashtag that im searching and if its only text i see it normally in my query results, but if i try to attach an image an write the same text it isnt returning me my post.
Can anybody help?thanx!

Comment: can anyone help please?im stil stuck on this

Comment: facing same problem. did have u have answer?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem, it is because a post with an attached picture is no longer considered as post but as a photo contained in the timeline pictures album which one is not searchable through the search api. Can't wait for real hashtag search reachable through the api.